# How can I bring a project on a Linux server to the local computer?

Tags: linux, git

I have a project running on linux - ubuntu server.
I cloned this project to the server with git.

I made many changes on the project on the server.

I need to get this new version on my local PC.
How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access to that Linux server, you can use an SSH URL like:

```sh
# on PC
git clone remoteUser@remoteServer:/path/to/repo
```

That supposes you have published your SSH public key to the remote server `~remoteUser/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Do I need to type in your remote server ip address or alias?

ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx
It has a name like

Comment: @utkumutlu Ideally the FQDN ([fully qualified name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)). If not possible, the IP. But in any case, you need the `remoteUser@` to connect to the right remote user.